# Getting an error with johannilssen action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

i'm developing an android app for 2.3.3, but I want to use an actionbar. After looking around for a bit I found johan nilssen ActionBar so I tried that.

I followed the whole [README](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/blob/master/README.md), but I'm getting error's at 2 functions which are not described.

```
actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, MainActivity.createIntent(this), R.drawable.ic_title_home_default));
actionBar.addAction(new IntentAction(this, createShareIntent(), R.drawable.ic_title_share_default));
```

It gives these error's

> The Method createIntent(MainActivity) is undefined for the type MainActivity

And

> The method createShareIntent() is undefined for the type MainActivity.

I tried to make the methods myself but that did not worked out because I don't know what I have to put in.

Comment: Post the link/stuff that u have followed.So that community can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `MainActivity` extends the appropriate class. (i.e. `Activity` or `ListActivity`) It may not be inheriting needed methods.

Also my internet is buggy so i cant check it out myself but [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) might be a good resource for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need to give this `Activity` new name and declare it in `Manifest` like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="package name.HomeActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you explain that a little more, I don't know what you mean exactly.